# How do I append text to the beginning and end of multiple text files in Bash?

Tags: shell-script, files, text-processing

I have a directory full of text files. My goal is to append text to the beginning and end of all of them. The text that goes at the beginning and end is the same for each file.

Based on code I got from the web, this is the code for appending to the beginning of the file:

```
echo -e 'var language = {\n$(cat $BASEDIR/Translations/Javascript/*.txt)' > $BASEDIR/Translations/Javascript/*.txt
```

This is the code for appending to the end of the file. The goal is to add the text `};` at the end of each file:

```
echo "};" >> $BASEDIR/Translations/Javascript/*.txt
```

The examples I drew from were for acting on individual files. I thought I'd try acting on multiple files using the wildcard, `*.txt`.

I might be making other mistakes as well. In any case, how do I append text to the beginning and end of multiple files?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To prepend text to a file you can use (with the GNU implementation of `sed`):

```
sed -i '1i some string' file
```

Appending text is as simple as

```
echo 'Some other string' >> file
```

The last thing to do is to put that into a loop which iterates over all the
files you intend to edit:

```
for file in *.txt; do
  sed -i '1i Some string' "$file" &&
  echo 'Some other string' >> "$file"
done
```

Comment: Might be worth mentioning (I missed this detail) that the `1i` at the beginning of the string passed to `sed` is very important here! It's an instruction to "insert before line 1"

Answer (score 9):

#### You can use GNU sed

Like already illustrated, you can insert lines of text right before and after matching lines of a file with `sed`, using the `i` and `a` command respectively.
What hasn't been shown is that you can do it with a one-liner and for **multiple files** at once.

The following will insert a line before the first `1i` and after the last line `$a`. The insertions will be executed for all files matching the glob `*.txt`.

```
sed -i -e '1ivar language = {' -e '$a};' -- *.txt
```

Both `i` and `a` do not only work with line numbers, but also on every line that matches a given pattern. This would insert a comment whenever a line contains `var y = 2;`:

```
sed -i -- '/var y = 2;/i//initialize variable y' *.js
```

Answer (score 6):

Fully POSIX compliant command, using [`ex`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html):

```
for f in *.txt; do printf '%s\n' 0a 'var language = {' . '$a' '};' . x | ex "$f"; done
```

---

If you run the `printf` portion of the command by itself, you will see the exact editing commands that it is passing to `ex`:

```
0a
var language = {
.
$a
};
.
x
```

`0a` means "Append text after line 0" (in other words, before the first line).  The next line is the literal text to "append" after line 0.  The period (`.`) on a line by itself ends the text to be appended.

`$a` means to append text after the last line of the file.

`x` means to save the changes and exit.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it in Perl:

```
for f in ./*txt; do
  perl -lpe 'BEGIN{print "First string"}END{print "Last string"}' "$f" > foo && 
  mv foo "$f";
done
```

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas adding `-i` instead of this file substitution does **not** work, it just prints to stdout.

Comment: @OlehPrypin, indeed your right. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Also has the right to be (with results in `.out` files):

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c '(echo HEAD;cat {};echo FOOT) > {}.out' \;
```

Another, more elaborated variant - source files replaced with result:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -exec sh -c '(echo HEAD;cat {};echo FOOT) > {}.tmp && mv {}.tmp {}' \; -print
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ex`:

```
ex -s +'bufdo!1s/^/HEAD/|$s/$/TAIL/' -cxa *.foo
```

where commands are:

- `bufdo!` executes below commands for each opened buffer/file (note: it's not [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html))
- `1s/^/HEAD/` - inserts `HEAD` text into the first line at the beginning of the line
- `$s/$/TAIL/` - appends `TAIL` text on the last line at the end of the line

and arguments are:

- `-s` - silent/quick mode
- `-cxa` - save all opened buffers/files and quit
- `*.foo` - all files in the current directory (`*`) with `foo` extension, use `**/*.foo` for recursivity (after enabling globstar: `shopt -s globstar`)

Comment: note bufdo is not POSIX http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html

Comment: @StevenPenny is right.  [I use POSIX specified features only,](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316508/135943) personally, for scripted edits.

Answer (score 1):

With `gnu awk`, using the `inplace` extension and `BEGINFILE`/`ENDFILE`:

```
gawk -i inplace 'BEGINFILE{print "INSERT"};ENDFILE{print "APPEND"};1' ./*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl one-liner to the rescue:

```
perl -i -pe'$_="FIRST LINE\n$_"if$.<2;$.=0,$_.="LAST LINE\n"if eof' *.txt
```

Comment: Perhaps explain the process of this (typically) terse program.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that makes use of the shell, and is considerably more readable than some other solutions is to use a basic loop and a temporary file:

```bsh
for file in $BASEDIR/Translations/Javascript/*.txt; do
    echo 'var language = {' | cat - "$file" > /tmp/my-modified-file && \
        echo '};' >> /tmp/my-modified-file && \
        mv /tmp/my-modified-file "$file"
done
```

This can be modified to a `while` loop if you need to pipe filenames from programs like `find` or `grep -l`:

```bsh
find /path/ -name '*someword*.myext' | while read -r file; do
    ...
done
```