# Inserting text with formatting at the start of a file with printf

Tags: bash, files, text-formatting, printf

I need to append something with particular formatting at the start of a text file. I have looked into [How do I append text to the beginning and end of multiple text files in Bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316508/359467), but
not sure how to adapt to my situation.

**Code**

```
printf 'Anything\tyou\twant\tto\tadd' 0a . x | ex printf.csv
```

**Expected output**

```
$ head -n 1 printf.csv;
Anything     you    want   to    add
```

Note: I would prefer a `printf` solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `printf` takes a format string as the first non-option argument. If that first argument doesn't make use of the format specifiers like `%s`, then the rest of the arguments are effectively useless. So, if you want to use the first argument because that's where escape characters like `\t` are interpreted, the rest of the text must be made to fit in there as well.
2. As that answer says:

   > `0a` means "Append text after line 0" (in other words, before the first line).  The next line is the literal text to "append" after line 0.  The period (`.`) on a line by itself ends the text to be appended.

   `0a` should come **before** the text to be appended.

So, something like:

```
printf '0a\nAnything\tyou\twant\tto\tadd\n.\nx\n' | ex printf.csv
```

Example:

```
% printf '0a\nAnything\tyou\twant\tto\tadd\n.\nx\n' | ex printf.csv
"printf.csv" [New file]
"printf.csv" [New file] 1 line, 25 characters
% cat printf.csv                                                                                 
Anything    you want    to  add
```

Comment: Might be more readable: `printf "%s\n" 0a $'Anything\tyou\twant\tto\tadd' . x`

Comment: Thanks all. All answers were good but I'm going to accept this because I understood the explanation better such as the `point 1`. 

Answer (score 4):

With `ex`, that would rather be something like:

```
printf '%b\n' 0a 'Anything\tyou\twant\tto\tadd' . x | ex -s printf.csv
```

or:

```
printf '0a\nAnything\tyou\twant\tto\tadd\n.\nx\n' | ex -s printf.csv
```

Note that the escape sequences recognised by `%b` arguments are not the same as that in the format argument. The former are the `echo` ones, and the latter the standard C-like ones (though many `printf` implementations have extension over them). That makes not difference for that `\t`, but it would for `\11` which you'd need to write  `\011` in a `%b` argument (at least if you wanted to be portable).

Another option, is to use `%s` but use ksh93-style `$'...'` quotes for the `\t` expansion:

```
printf '%s\n' 0a $'Anything\tyou\twant\tto\tadd' . x | ex -s printf.csv
```

Where they're supported (ksh93, zsh, bash, FreeBSD sh, busybox ash at least), those `$'...'` quotes usually support the standard C escapes (with extensions) like in the format argument to `printf` (unlike `%b` arguments or `echo`).

Comment: Cool. I am going to use the last approach.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `cat` command. It is designed to conCAT files.

Given you have file `test.txt` with contents:

```
Test file
Here it is
```

You can append some text on begining with `printf` and `cat` like this:
`printf "Some fancy text\n" | cat - test.txt`.

```
Some fancy text
Test file
Here it is
```

You can redirect output to other file and finally save it in the place of old one it that is the case.

`printf "Some fancy text\n" | cat - test.txt > /tmp/insertTestFile && mv /tmp/insertTestFile test.txt`

This is only a proof of concept. In real life scenario you should consider following limitations:

- Creating files in `/tmp` directory with fixed names is bad idea. Consider using `tempfile` command to create file and store it's name in variable if you need so
- Using `mv` across different filesystems causes file to be copied
- Above solution will create new file and abandon previous one with it's permissions and acl

My intention was to show simple solution that is easy to understand to beginners. Many thanks for all people commenting this answer and pointing out things that may be misleading.

PS. My favourite approach here would be using `sed -i '1s/^/Added text\n/' file.txt`

Comment: A nice beginner friendly approach!

Comment: @massisenergy, but it's important to warn of the implications there. Creating and writing to tempfiles with fixed name in a world-writable directory like `/tmp` is very bad practice. That introduces a security vulnerability as an attacker can create a symlink with that name and let you overwrite any file you have write access to.

Comment: Also `/tmp` is often on its own filesystem. That means that the `mv` would have to do a copy-and-remove instead of just rename, which means the file will end up being written twice.

Comment: Also note that `test.txt` will be replaced with a brand new file, so with possibly different metadata like ownership, permissions, ACLs, extended attributes, etc.

Comment: Here the two commands should be chained with `&&` instead of `;` as it's important the second one not be run if the first one failed.

Comment: Thanks for all your remarks. I've corrected my answer so it will not mislead others so much.